# Python multiprocessing - Is it possible to introduce a fixed time delay between individual processes?

Tags: python, multithreading, batch-file, multiprocessing

I have searched and cannot find an answer to this question elsewhere. Hopefully I haven't missed something.

I am trying to use Python multiprocessing to essentially batch run some proprietary models in parallel. I have, say, 200 simulations, and I want to batch run them ~10-20 at a time. My problem is that the proprietary software crashes if two models happen to start at the same / similar time. I need to introduce a delay between processes spawned by multiprocessing so that each new model run waits a little bit before starting.

So far, my solution has been to introduced a random time delay at the start of the child process before it fires off the model run. However, this only reduces the probability of any two runs starting at the same time, and therefore I still run into problems when trying to process a large number of models. I therefore think that the time delay needs to be built into the multiprocessing part of the code but I haven't been able to find any documentation or examples of this.

Edit: I am using Python 2.7

This is my code so far:

```
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import subprocess
import multiprocessing

def runmodels(arg):
    sleep(np.random.rand(1,1)*120) # this is my interim solution to reduce the probability that any two runs start at the same time, but it isn't a guaranteed solution
    subprocess.call(arg) # this line actually fires off the model run

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    arguments =     [big list of runs in here
                    ]    

    count = 12
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = count)
    r = pool.imap_unordered(runmodels, arguments)      
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: `imap_unordered()` returns an iterator, you should consume it e.g., `for result in pool.imap_unordered(...):`

Comment: In that situation, what would I normally do within that loop (i.e. in the line after the for statement)?

Comment: handle the result of an individual simulation if any and/or report the progress (`'\r{x} out of {y} simulations done'`).

Comment: The point is that, you should consume the iterator explicitly (whatever the actual `multiprocessing` implementation is). If you don't need results; use `deque(r, maxlen=0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this with thread and semaphore :

```
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import threading


def runmodels(arg):
    subprocess.call(arg)
    sGlobal.release() # release for next launch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    global sGlobal
    sGlobal = threading.Semaphore(12) #Semaphore for max 12 Thread
    arguments =  [big list of runs in here
                ]
    for arg in arguments :
        sGlobal.acquire() # Block if more than 12 thread
        t = threading.Thread(target=runmodels, args=(arg,))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
        sleep(1)

    for t in threads :
        t.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I'm having a few issues:
- sGlobal = threading.Semaphore(n) doesn't seem to limit the number of simultaneous runs. It just seems to fires off as many as it wants.
- sTempo = threading.Semaphore(n) doesn't seem to affect the delay between two runs. The only number that makes a difference to the delay is the sleep(n).
- If all processes successfully complete, I get an error at the end that says: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main_thread' .

Any further help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Scratch my comment about the sTempo semaphore, I now understand how that is supposed to work. However, the sGlobal semaphore is still firing off more than n model runs.

Comment: After some further investigation, I think the unlimited threads are caused because the subprocess isn't blocking. Although, I understood that subprocess.call() is meant to be blocking.

Comment: I did a mistake. The Semaphore didn't block because the code launched the Thread and directly did the release on the semaphore (so didn't stop). I have edit the code : the semaphore release is now in the thread so the release is do when the subrocess is finish. I hope it will be ok this time :)

Comment: For AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main_thread'. I suppose it because i use python 3.4 and you use python 2.X. I have edit the code for python version 2.X. Next time give your python version in the problem ;)

Comment: This works brilliantly, thank you! I don't enough reputation to upvote but I have marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: `sDelay` is useless here (to make it useful, you have to use it in more than one thread/process. Why would you try to reimplement `multiprocess.Pool()` poorely?

Comment: sDelay  isn't useless you can have 12 thread at the same time ... Try with and without you will see the different on the start of different thread

Comment: `sDelay` is acquired/released in the main thread (the one, the only). Remove `sDelay` and see that nothing changes

Comment: Ahhhh yees  .. I see now ;).

Comment: I've just tested the updated code and it works well.

Answer (score 7):

`multiprocessing.Pool()` already limits number of processes *running* concurrently.

You could use a lock, to separate the *starting* time of the processes (not tested):

```
import threading
import multiprocessing

def init(lock):
    global starting
    starting = lock

def run_model(arg):
    starting.acquire() # no other process can get it until it is released
    threading.Timer(1, starting.release).start() # release in a second
    # ... start your simulation here

if __name__=="__main__":
   arguments = ...
   pool = Pool(processes=12, 
               initializer=init, initargs=[multiprocessing.Lock()])
   for _ in pool.imap_unordered(run_model, arguments):
       pass
```

Comment: worked for me and seems simpler than previous answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested by [jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30368163/) caused problems for me as a result of starting a new thread with `threading.Timer`. If the worker just so happens to finish *before* the timer does, the timer is killed and the lock is never released.

I propose an alternative route, in which each successive worker will wait until enough time has passed since the start of the previous one. This seems to have the same desired effect, but without having to rely on another child process.

```python
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def init(shared_val):
    global start_time
    start_time = shared_val

def run_model(arg):
    with start_time.get_lock():
        wait_time = max(0, start_time.value - time.time())
        time.sleep(wait_time)
        start_time.value = time.time() + 1.0 # Specify interval here
    # ... start your simulation here

if __name__=="__main__":
   arguments = ...
   pool = mp.Pool(processes=12, 
                  initializer=init, initargs=[mp.Value('d')])
   for _ in pool.imap_unordered(run_model, arguments):
       pass
```